# Trying to make ip list with an ip range

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script that generates all IPs that start with the first 2 segments that are user input. Ex: you input 123.123 and the script will make a list of all IPs from 123.123.0.0 to 123.123.255.255

So to generate the 3rd segment I've tried to use a for loop to indent the user input with a dot and then a range of all numbers from 0 to 255 and then append everything to a list and it worked, for the 4th segment i tried the same thing but because i tried to indent a list with a string and a range it didn't work.

```
ip_class=input("Enter IP range: ")

ip_templist=[]

for no in range(0,256):
    ip_templist.append(ip_class+"."+str(no))
```

If you have a better way to do it with a module function that would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a double list comprehension, you can do it in one line.

```
ip_class = input("Enter IP range: ")
res = ["%s.%d.%d" % (ip_class, x, y) for x in range(256) for y in range(256)]
print(res)
```

This does not check for a valid first input, to `ip_class` could be literally anything.

Comment: Thank you, I already have an input validation function so there's no problem